# Is there an easy way to identify course codes and course names from university's UI pages

Tags: web-scraping, nlp, nltk

I need to pull course codes and course names from university course catalogs. However, I need to do this for all universities and writing codes for each page of every university is a daunting task. One solution is to get the raw text from the html pages and then extract the course codes and course names from this raw text. However, the format of course codes and course names keep changing and this cannot be done via regex. I thought of using NLP to train models but again this would need a lot of training data where I would need to manually identify the course codes and course names. Is there a package or method I could use to get these course codes and course names easily from raw text?

Answer (score 2):

you should probably look for xhr requests loading the data if it a dynamic spa or component system. if the use apis I would look for those and find similarities and most likely they json data keys won't vary too much. however, it is what is man. you're scraping data which is not particularly viewed as the most ethical thing and with that I think accepting the challenge of some leg work should be expected. if they wanted you to easily pull their data they would offer an API that you could interface to and if they don't you are kind of in a grey area to be expecting a silver bullet solution. however you can try nlp or ocr, but if it is like you say it is not similar site by site until you retrieve your training data it won't be great at guessing just as much as you can do with regex or html parsing for text data.

Potentially, you might be able to find models or spaces with helpful information on OCR, NLP, or other AI/ML approaches on sites like github, huggyface, kaggle and more.

It seems hard to find a good dataset for course data and I happened to come across this dataset on github. However, I cannot ensure the link will forever be valid. So it may be worth grabbing that data while you can.

https://github.com/Siddharth1698/Coursera-Course-Dataset

@abhi, I came across this today that would be very helpful for you. you need to install something like puppeteer or selenium so that the JavaScript can execute. your issue here is that you are only rendering the static content.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34798924)

Comment: @Itération122442, I think I do exactly that. I said to look for xhr requests on dynamic js spas. I also explain the ethics of it. Then go back to his point about using NLP/OCR AI and that it may be difficult to find that training data. I then link example from kaggle and a dataset. Then to give thought on another approach I speak on the use of puppeteer or selenium and their advantages due to rendering non static content. Then link a guid to it. I think I didn't give a link only answer and politely disagree with your review. Expecting someone to supply a data set and model on SO is not expectd

Comment: @Itération122442, I guess I could have just said no to OPs Is there a package or method I could use to get these course codes and course names easily from raw text? Though a language wasn't given or model or dataset... This is not github, hence one would link someone to it.

Comment: *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline* --> [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Itération122442 could of simply said that link doesn't work... There ya go.